# Joblib doesn't run on multiple cores

Tags: python, joblib

I need to fit multiple classifiers (from scikit-learn) and score them.

```
clf1.fit(x_fit,Y_fit)
clf2.fit(x_fit,Y_fit)
clf3.fit(x_fit,Y_fit)
clf4.fit(x_fit,Y_fit)

acc1 = clf1.score(x_score,Y_score)
acc2 = clf2.score(x_score,Y_score)
acc3 = clf3score(x_score,Y_score)
acc4 = clf4.score(x_score,Y_score)
```

This turns out to be very slow. Therefore I want to make use of joblib and make my code execute in parallel. Here is my code

```
def fit_score(x_fit, Y_fit, x_score, Y_score, clf):
    clf.fit(x_fit, Y_fit)
    return clf.score(x_score, Y_score)

acc1, acc2, acc3, acc4 = Parallel(n_jobs=4)(delayed(fit_score)(x_fit, Y_fit, x_score, Y_score, clf) for clf in [clf1, clf2, clf3, clf4])
```

Unfortunately this doesn’t seem to work very well. I am observing CPU usage with `htop` and it appears that this is still running on only one single core. I searched for a comparable thread, however most people are suffering from an increased runtime caused by the overhead from using parallel. But in my case it doesn't seem to use parallel at all.

Am I doing anything wrong?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your answer. I have finally figured out where the problem was.
Unfortunately I found out, that the code I posted above is actually running on four cores, as i want it to (each classifier is fitted and scored on its on core). However, as three of the four classifiers are finished much earlier than the fourth, it is barely visible, that the code really runs multicore.

However thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Some sklearn routines only use 1 core, but some are designed for use of several cores. Sklearn has a jobkib-based back end you should try.  https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.parallel_backend.html

I think fixing the rest requires you share details on the OS and Python.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using accelerated implementations of algorithms - such as scikit-learn-intelex - https://github.com/intel/scikit-learn-intelex

By using this natively optimized libs you can get much better performance even on limited number of cores.

First install package

```sh
pip install scikit-learn-intelex
```

And then add in your python script

```py
from sklearnex import patch_sklearn
patch_sklearn()
```